# Book for learning stochastic processes for a beginner

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am a social science student interested in learning stochastic processes.
The book used in my university is Grimmett and Stirzaker. I tried to study discrete time markov process from it and was able to understand the proofs. However, I probably won't be able to survive without solving many numerical examples. I was wondering if there is any book that can be a good supplement for it? Is Durett's introductory book good for this purpose?

Best,

Comment: If you want to understand the theory of stochastic processes, then you will need a solid background in real analysis, particularly in measure theory.